# using java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle in clojure

Tags: clojure, methodhandle

I'm following a tutorial here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-handles

In clojure, I've got a simple example:

```
(import (java.lang.invoke MethodHandles
                          MethodHandles$Lookup
                          MethodType
                          MethodHandle))

(defonce +lookup+ (MethodHandles/lookup))

(def ^MethodHandle concat-handle (.findVirtual +lookup+
                                 String
                                 "concat"
                                 (MethodType/methodType String String)))

(.invokeExact concat-handle (into-array Object ["hello" "there"]))
```

which gives an error:

```
Unhandled java.lang.invoke.WrongMethodTypeException
 expected (String,String)String but found (Object[])Object

         Invokers.java:  476  java.lang.invoke.Invokers/newWrongMethodTypeException
         Invokers.java:  485  java.lang.invoke.Invokers/checkExactType
                  REPL:   26  hara.object.handle/eval17501
                  REPL:   26  hara.object.handle/eval17501
         Compiler.java: 7062  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
         Compiler.java: 7025  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
              core.clj: 3206  clojure.core/eval
              core.clj: 3202  clojure.core/eval
              main.clj:  243  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print/f
```

is there a way to get `invoke` working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.invokeWithArguments` which will figure out the correct arity from the supplied arguments:

```
(.invokeWithArguments concat-handle (object-array ["hello" "there"]))
=> "hellothere"
```

Or you can use `.invoke`, but you'll need `MethodHandle.asSpreader` to apply the varargs correctly to `String.concat` which has fixed arity:

```
(def ^MethodHandle other-handle
  (.asSpreader
    concat-handle
    (Class/forName "[Ljava.lang.String;") ;; String[].class
    2))

(.invoke other-handle (into-array String ["hello" "there"]))
=> "hellothere"
```

I'm not sure how to make this work with `.invokeExact` from Clojure, if it's possible.

> The symbolic type descriptor at the call site of invokeExact must exactly match this method handle's type. No conversions are allowed on arguments or return values.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23435078) has more explanation on restrictions of `.invoke` and `.invokeExact`.

Comment: ah brilliant. thanks for that. would you know if there is some sort of performance penalty for using `invokeWithArguments`?

Comment: @zcaudate I would assume some overhead, and looks like your benchmarks _reflect_ ;) that.

Answer (score 1):

Some interesting benchmarks based on @TaylorWood's answer:

```
(with-out-str
  (time (dotimes [i 1000000]
          (.concat "hello" "there"))))
=> "\"Elapsed time: 8.542214 msecs\"\n"


(with-out-str
  (def concat-fn (fn [a b] (.concat a b)))
  (time (dotimes [i 1000000]
          (concat-fn "hello" "there"))))
=> "\"Elapsed time: 3600.357352 msecs\"\n"

(with-out-str
  (def concat-anno (fn [^String a b] (.concat a b)))
  (time (dotimes [i 1000000]
          (concat-anno "hello" "there"))))
=> "\"Elapsed time: 16.461237 msecs\"\n"

(with-out-str
  (def concat-reflect (.? String "concat" :#))
  (time (dotimes [i 1000000]
          (concat-reflect "hello" "there"))))
=> "\"Elapsed time: 1804.522226 msecs\"\n"

(with-out-str
  (def ^MethodHandle concat-handle
    (.findVirtual +lookup+
                  String
                  "concat"
                  (MethodType/methodType String String)))
  (time (dotimes [i 1000000]
          (.invokeWithArguments concat-handle (into-array Object ["hello" "there"])))))
=> "\"Elapsed time: 1974.824815 msecs\"\n" 

(with-out-str
  (def ^MethodHandle concat-spread
    (.asSpreader concat-handle
                 (Class/forName "[Ljava.lang.String;") ;; String[].class
                 2))
  (time (dotimes [i 1000000]
          (.invoke other-handle (into-array String ["hello" "there"])))))
=> "\"Elapsed time: 399.779913 msecs\"\n"
```